# How to document same methods from different systems in activity diagrams

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

We are documenting a system which will use third party API's, for this we will introduce a service layer which will call API methods and it will act as an Adapter for third party API, our service layer will have method names same as API.

e.g.

```
1   UI          >> MyService    >>  API 

Get User     Get User        Get User
```

---

```
2   UI          >> MyService    >>  API 

Delete User  Delete User     Delete User
```

---

```
3   UI          >> MyService    >>  API 

Create User  Create User     Create User
```

---

for this action names for each system are same and being repeat for each lane which looks awkward. Apart from this we can not directly pass the response from third party api for our UI so in return trip we have to mention an action in our Service layer this action name also looks awkward.

Is there any consistent way on convention we need to follow for this scenario.
Kindly refer this activity :[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would simply not create diagrams for such trivial cases. If you document that in a sentence (or two) it will definitely suffice.

However, if you feel the need to create a diagram you could abbreviate that by combining the above mentioned in a CRUD way:

```
UI          >> MyService    >>  API 

CRUD User   CRUD User       CRUD User
```

Comment: the example i have mentioned is for different diagrams, these are three diffrent cases. please refere image.

Comment: Well, this is my advice. You can follow or use another way. I for myself have no other suggestion. Or maybe I don't see your problem.